# Laravel connect with external db?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I try to connect with a external database with my laravel application and got following error messages:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                            
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lextern and table_name = migrations) 

  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

Connection:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db_ip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lextern
DB_USERNAME=lextern_root
DB_PASSWORD=db_pw
```

If I do that from localhost then it works...

I don't installed mysql on the server, but wish to connect with external DB, do I have to setup still something on my server?

Comment: You will need to install the mysql-client on the server in order to use the `mysql` functions to connect to external mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Your external database serve does not have mysql server or it's not not running.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

will start the server.